# Java: "implements operator?"

Tags: java, generics, operators

I have some functions containing much calculation stuff. All calculations are done using operators [], *, /, + and -. Eyerything else is loops and tests. So those same functions "could" be used on any type that implements those operators, eg. double, float, int, long etc. For performance reasons, i just use basic types. Is there any way to do this generic?

Also – for perfomace reasons, i dont want to cast floats and ints to double and calc in double. i want to calc in int on int, in float on floats and in double on doubles. I just dont want to write 3 times the same code that just differs in the type used.

For example, guess you have

```
public double doSomething(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b + 1;
}
```

of course, actual fn do much more than this.

I think a trick would be something like

```
public T doSomething(T a, T b)
{
    return staticAdd(staticMul(a,b),1);
}
```

…and define basic operations as static fn for all used types. But as those are not inlined, this would add another fn-call.

Is there a way in java to do some thing like
   `<T implements +, implements ->` …?

Comment: Java does not support operator overloading.

Comment: There is no way to do that in Java.

Comment: @Quirliom: That wasnt the question.

Comment: "But as those are not inlined, this would add another fn-call." The JVM will inline them if they are called enough.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion you give for defining methods like `staticAdd` isn't as bad as you might think at first. One of the things HotSpot will do for you (when it's in the mood) is [inline code](http://blog.headius.com/2007/07/understanding-jvm-jit-and-helping-it.html). If you define such functions for the types you're concerned with, you may well get decent performance.

That said, you're still going to be dealing with autoboxing, since you can't genericize methods on primitives. If the performance is truly that critical, you may be stuck writing multiple method signatures.
Consider, though, that it's rumored that primitives may [go away entirely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_10) in future versions of Java/the JVM. Of course the penalty for dealing with the wrapped types isn't nil, but it's approaching negligible in many applications.

Answer (score 1):

The only operator overloading Java supports is `+` as stringify and concatenate. If you want this, you want one of the non-Java JVM languages.

But, recall the old joke: “If you want LISP, you know where to find it.”

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it is not possible. Java being statically typed, operations cannot be abstracted from the underlying type.

For example, you cannot have arithmetic operations defined on Number so as to abstract away the underlying type (Short, Integer, etc..).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **NO**, there isn't a way to do this. The type system isn't strong enough to express this sort of thing in Java.

Also since primitive data types are not supported in Generics you may have to use the wrapper classes like `Integers`, `Float` etc., Hackiest way to accomplish using Wrapper class would be as below,

```
public class Calculator<T extends Number> {
    T add(T a, T b) {
        if (a instanceof Double) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf((a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue()));
        } else if (a instanceof Float) {
            return (T) Float.valueOf(((a.floatValue() + b.floatValue())));
        } else if (a instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(((a.intValue() + b.intValue())));
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

You can call the same as below.

```
Calculator<Double> c1 = new Calculator<Double>();
mc.add(1.0, 1.1);

Calculator<Integer> c1 = new Calculator<Integer>();
mc.add(1, 2);
```